# JPA query to retrieve nested entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like query a nested object, `TyreChange` of a abstract class in JPA. The model looks like this:

**Car**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.All, mappedBy = "car")
    private List<MechanicVisit> listMechanicVisit = new ArrayList();
    //others
}
```

**MechanicVisit**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class mechanicVisit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private LocalDateTime visitDate;
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = fetchType.LAZY)
    private Car car;
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.All, mappedBy = "mechanicVisit")
    Private List<Task> tasks;
    //others
}
```

**Task**

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@MappedSuperClass
public class abstract Task (
    @Id 
    private Long taskId;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FethType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private MechanicVisit mechanicVisit;
}
```

**TyreChange**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class TyreChage extends Task {
    private String name;
    private Double size;
    private Double value;
}
```

I have tried this query on the Car repository:

```
@Query(SELECT c FROM Car c
LEFT JOIN FETCH c.mechanicVisit m
LEFT JOIN FETCH m.tyreChange
WHERE c.id = :id"
Optional<Car> getCarwithTyreChange(@Param("id") Long id);
```

However this query does not work.

**Q:** How would I construct this query?

I do not understand if the query objects in JPA follow the db structure or the entity structure (should tasks be referenced in the query).

**UPDATE**

There are many mechanic visits for each car, so the query should be more like:

```
@Query(SELECT c FROM Car c
LEFT JOIN FETCH c.listMechanicVisits m
LEFT JOIN FETCH m.task
WHERE c.id = :id"
Optional<Car> getCarwithTyreChange(@Param("id") Long id);
```

The error I get when I try this is:

Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.nz.car.repository.CardRepository.getCarwithTyres(java.lang.Long)!

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Can you provide the error message? At first, I can say that second `LEFT JOIN FETCH` is wrong, should be `m.tasks` instead of `m.tyreChange`.

Comment: @birca123 is correct) Though i think, the question will be solved with usage of `@EntityGraph` annotation constructed manually or through plugins.

Comment: @birca123 so you still reference task even though its a abstract class?

Comment: @AlGrant the point is to reference a field, and you don't have a field named `tyreChange` in `MechanicVisit` class.

Comment: @birca123 right, so even though task is a abstract, and doesn't create a table in the database it still is used in JPQL queries?

Comment: `SELECT c FROM Car c
JOIN FETCH c.listMechanicVisits m
JOIN FETCH m.task
WHERE c.id = :id` should work. No need for a left join IMO. Also include the full stacktrace to exceptions

Comment: @AlGrant That's right.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer it doesn't like the FETCH JOIN m.tasks - error : cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Comment: and that is correct, since you want to eagerly load them

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of your query? I'm guessing by the method name you are looking just for the TyreChange tasks associated to a car - the query you are issuing will return the car with all MechanicVisit and all tasks performed populated. JPA fetch joins don't allow you to filter the data returned so that the entity returned reflects exactly what is in the DB. If you are looking for only TyreChange tasks associated to a car, you will need to query on them directly

Comment: As for the "cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags", Hibernate doesn't like fetching over multiple *ToMany relationships in one query. Other providers don't have this problem, but it is better to not return N*M rows for a single car, which is what happens with the fetch joins. You might try letting JPA build the tasks in a batch query instead, using @BatchSize or https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-how-to-fetch-associations-in-batches/ , but I don't know how well they work with table per class inheritance. Joined or single table inheritance is usually a better option if possible.

Comment: @Chris I am new to JPA, so a lot of reading and learning going on. Another good query to see would be all the TyeChange tasks associated to a car. I understand that you can use projection to setup the result object (but not with native queries?)

Comment: Do you just want TyreChange associated to a car? "select tc from TyreChange tc where tc.mechanicVisit.car.id = :carId" This will return a list without needing to fetch visits or the car. I don't know that you have the task->mechanicVisit relationship mapped correctly though, as it should probably be a ManyToOne.